# VLOOKUP returning N/A when it has previously found the value

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I have a list of country codes for records which I am trying to convert to country names in my spreadsheet. I created a lookup table on a separate tab, and used the formula: =VLOOKUP(F31,'Country Code Lookup'!C1:D249,2,FALSE)

Then I dragged the formula down the column to fill in the data. Everything was working but then I noticed that some cells were giving me N/A... even when the data had been correctly been found at an earlier point in the column (see attached graphic). [image: Screenshot]

As you can see, it already found Finland earlier in the table, but yielded an N/A later. I tried this on both Excel and Libre Office Calc btw, and it came up with the same errors. The country codes were TRIMmed from another column to remove spaces that were in there, so I thought there might be an issue with hidden characters or something, so I deleted FI in the second instance, and put it in manually to see if that fixed the issue. Nope. Also deleted the value from the lookup table and manually reentered... same result. So now I am at a loss as to what to do, as this error is popping up all over the place and my spreadsheet is over 1000 rows long, so I don't want to be manually correcting the errors. Can anyone provide some insight on how I might solve this?

Comment: `C$1:D$249` - lock the rows. Or just use `C:D`.

Comment: That worked great -- thanks so much!

Comment: If you're going to be working with formulas in Excel, I highly recommend you reading up on absolute vs relative references.